# no output file while scraping using selenium driver

Tags: python, linux, selenium, scrapy

i'm new to scrapy and selenium.
I have a script that should collect data from a dynamic web site using selenium as standard CSV scrapy output is not created while using scrapy alone.

Therefore to collect dynamic content i use selenium driver.
I'm able to retrieve the content  but i have an issue to create the output CSV file.

if i run the script using :

```
scrapy runspider free_foe_player.py -o free_foe_player.csv
```

the csv file is created before the driver is closed and therefore the csv file is empty.

if i run the script using:

```
scrapy runspider free_foe_player.py
```

the script is correctly run but the script does not create the csv file even if i have the following code in the script:

```
with open('players.csv', 'w+', newline='') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
   writer.writerow("test")
```

just to test if the file is really created.

```
here is the complete code:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Spider
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import csv


class FreeFoePlayerSpider(Spider):
    name = 'free_foe_player'
    allowed_domains = ['www.forge-db.com/fr/fr11/players/?server=fr11']

    def start_requests(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/tester/repository/web/foe-python/chromedriver')
        self.driver.get('https://www.forge-db.com/fr/fr11/players/?server=fr11')

        #driver.implicitly_wait(implicit_wait)

        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        players = sel.xpath('//table[@id="players"]/tbody/tr/td[3]/a').extract()  

        for player in players:
            yield Request(player, callback=self.parse_player)

        # Close the selenium driver, so in fact it closes the testing browser
        self.driver.quit()

    def parse_player(self, response):
        with open('players.csv', 'w+', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
            writer.writerow("test")
```

I searched on internet but i was not able to find appropriate help for my issue.
Thx for helping me.

Comment: whatt happen when you uncomment the `implicit-wait` line ? try giving `implicitly_wait(10)`

Comment: In this case, selenium driver is not closed and the csv file is still empty and created immediately when i run the script.... so it seems created before even yield is executed